# how to change type of date number to date Angular

Tags: angular

I have a simple question :
I try to send the date from angular to the backend as type date

I get and send data us in this interface :

```js
export interface Inventaire {
  CDEXERC: number;
  AGENT: number;
  DECAFFE: number;
  DATE_INV: Date;
  OBSRV: string;
  VLD: number;
  CREATED: Date;
  MODIFIED: Date;
  User_ID: string;
}
```

I try to post a new object so I need the date, I try to make a variable `mydate=Date.now()` but in this case, mydate  is a number and the pipe is only work in the HTML `{{ mydate | date }}`

I just want to get the same resualt `{{mydate | date }}` but without using html ( in the ts file )

I try this but it show me error `DATE_INV:myDate|date,`

please help I know it's simple and I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the date pipe in your .ts file.  You use it as you would a different service.

So, in your ctor:

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {  }
```

and then when you want to use it:

```
mydate = this.datePipe.transform(Date.now(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

You can also use a different format if that suits you better.

Just remember, that as with other serivices, you will need to provide it. So for example, in your module, add `providers: [DatePipe]`